# Monaco Editor doesn't resize inside Splitpanes

Tags: css, vuejs2, vuetify.js, monaco-editor

package.json (question related dependencies)

```
"dependencies": {
  "monaco-editor-webpack-plugin": "^1.9.1",
  "splitpanes": "^2.4.1",
  "vue-monaco": "^1.2.2"
}
```

vue.config.js

```
const MonacoEditorPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ],
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new MonacoEditorPlugin({
        languages: ['javascript', 'typescript']
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

CodeEditor.vue

```
<template>
  <Splitpanes
    style="100vh"
    class="default-theme"
  >
    <Pane size="40">
      <!-- Very long text -->
    </Pane>
    <Pane size="60">
      <MonacoEditor
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
        v-model="code"
        theme="vs-dark"
        language="javascript"
        :options="options"
      />
    </Pane>
  </Splitpanes>
</template>

<script>
import { Splitpanes, Pane } from 'splitpanes'
import MonacoEditor from 'vue-monaco'
import 'splitpanes/dist/splitpanes.css'

export default {

  components: {
    Splitpanes,
    Pane,
    MonacoEditor
  },

  data () {
    return {

      code: 'const noop = () => {}',

      options: {
        automaticLayout: true
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Monaco Editor doesn't resize, even though I set automaticLayout to true. What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** With monaco-editor-vue and monaco-editor-webpack-plugin 1.8.2 everything works fine (but I can't use it because it doesn't support v-model).

Comment: What's the real problem? Does the editor not resize, that is, fill its container all the time, or does it not properly layout its content?

Comment: @MikeLischke my apologies, I don't understand your question. The editor doesn't update its width and height during pane resize.